# rxJava - How Observable can emit from the body of .create method?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am looking at the following example taken from GitHub, that clearly works, but I don't understand why:

```
Observable<String> fsObs = CreateObservable.listFolder(
                Paths.get("src", "com", "alex", "experiment"),
                "*.java")
                .flatMap(path -> CreateObservable.from(path));

// CreateObservable.listFolder
public static Observable<Path> listFolder(Path dir, String glob) {
        return Observable.<Path>create(subscriber -> {
            try {
                DirectoryStream<Path> stream =
                        Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, glob);

                subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> {
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }));
                Observable.<Path>from(stream).subscribe(subscriber);
            } catch (DirectoryIteratorException ex) {
                subscriber.onError(ex);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                subscriber.onError(ioe);
            }
        });
    }
```

Notice that  `Observable.<Path>from(stream).subscribe(subscriber)` is being created. How does this line emits messages into `flatMap(path -> CreateObservable.from(path)) ?`

Answer (score 1):

Because [`DirectoryStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) implements `Iterable` which would iterate over the entries in a directory, and [`Observable.from(Iterable)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#from(java.lang.Iterable)) converts the sequence into an Observable emitting the items in the sequence, which is the entries in a directory. Then, when a subscriber subscribes to the Observable, it will be receive items being emitted.

A simplified version of `Observable.<Path>from(stream).subscribe(subscriber)` is just:

```
for (Path path : stream) {
    subscriber.onNext(path);
}
```

Calling `subscriber.onNext` is how the data being emitted.

Comment: (pt1)This line `return Observable.<Path>create` gives us Observable<Path> that will be passed as a second parameter to .flatmap http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMap%28rx.functions.Func1%29  
However, inside the lambda function in the `create(-> {...})` method , we also create another Observable<Path> from the `DirectoryStream`(which implements the `Iterable` interface).
How the emissions from inside Observable in the lambda, end up outside in the `.flatmap` ? All the emissions from the inside observable end up being send to subscriber.

Comment: (pt2)Maybe, I have a gap in Java knowledge, but to me inside/outside Observable<Path> are totally disconnected entities. It would make sense if it was written as `return Observable<Path>from(stream).subscribe(subscriber);`, however `.subscribe(subscriber)` return `Subscription`